# Sgin in with Google for web: switching account changes the SESSION on server, but still the same account on Google button

Tags: google-signin, google-api-php-client, google-api-javascript-client

implementation: "[Google JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference)" with button, without One Tap.
Scenario:
The user had two Google accounts A and B, while already logged in with A, without logging out A account he then switched to B account by [Google button](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#GsiButtonConfiguration), and the server changed the `$_SESSION` accordingly.
Issue:
After that, the user now has B `$_SESSION` on the server, whilist Google button still show account A icon.
Tried to logout the user when he switches account, but there don't seem an event I can attach to.